# How to load dynamically generated kml/xml file into embedded Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hello any advice to this problem would be greatly appreciated as it seems as though it should be a simple issue however it is causing me a great deal of difficulty.

I have been following the tutorial "Using PHP/MySQL with Google Maps" located at https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax to generate a kml/xml file. The kml file I am generating differs from the file seen in the example in that I am generating the polygon boundaries of a series of buildings rather than just creating place marks at specific locations. The code for this page is seen below...

```
// Creates the Document.
    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

    // Creates the root KML element and appends it to the root document.
    $node = $dom->createElementNS('http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1', 'kml');
    $parNode = $dom->appendChild($node);

    // Creates a KML Document element and append it to the KML element.
    $dnode = $dom->createElement('Document');
    $docNode = $parNode->appendChild($dnode);

    //Style 1
    //Set Style ID
    $restStyleNode = $dom->createElement('Style');
    $restStyleNode->setAttribute('id', '#style1');
    $restIconstyleNode = $dom->createElement('IconStyle');
    $restIconstyleNode->setAttribute('id', 'BuildingIcon');

    //Set LineStyle
    $restIconNode = $dom->createElement('LineStyle');
    $restHref = $dom->createElement('colour', 'FF990000');
    $restIconNode->appendChild($restHref);
    $restWidth = $dom->createElement('width', '2');
    $restIconNode->appendChild($restWidth);
    $restIconstyleNode->appendChild($restIconNode);
    $restStyleNode->appendChild($restIconstyleNode);
    $docNode->appendChild($restStyleNode);

    //Set Polystyle
    $restIconNode = $dom->createElement('PolyStyle');
    $restHref = $dom->createElement('colour', 'FFCC0000');
    $restIconNode->appendChild($restHref);
    $restFill = $dom->createElement('fill', '1');
    $restIconNode->appendChild($restFill);
    $restOutline = $dom->createElement('outline', '1');
    $restIconNode->appendChild($restOutline);
    $restIconstyleNode->appendChild($restIconNode);
    $restStyleNode->appendChild($restIconstyleNode);
    $docNode->appendChild($restStyleNode);

    //Style 2
    //Set Style ID
    $restStyleNode = $dom->createElement('Style');
    $restStyleNode->setAttribute('id', '#style2');
    $restIconstyleNode = $dom->createElement('IconStyle');
    $restIconstyleNode->setAttribute('id', 'HighfieldIcon');

    //Set LineStyle
    $restIconNode = $dom->createElement('LineStyle');
    $restHref = $dom->createElement('colour', 'ff000000');
    $restIconNode->appendChild($restHref);
    $restWidth = $dom->createElement('width', '2');
    $restIconNode->appendChild($restWidth);
    $restIconstyleNode->appendChild($restIconNode);
    $restStyleNode->appendChild($restIconstyleNode);
    $docNode->appendChild($restStyleNode);

    //Set Polystyle
    $restIconNode = $dom->createElement('PolyStyle');
    $restHref = $dom->createElement('colour', 'ff000000');
    $restIconNode->appendChild($restHref);
    $restFill = $dom->createElement('fill', '1');
    $restIconNode->appendChild($restFill);
    $restOutline = $dom->createElement('outline', '1');
    $restIconNode->appendChild($restOutline);
    $restIconstyleNode->appendChild($restIconNode);
    $restStyleNode->appendChild($restIconstyleNode);
    $docNode->appendChild($restStyleNode);

    // Iterates through the MySQL results, creating one Placemark for each row.
    while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            // Creates a Placemark and append it to the Document.

            $node = $dom->createElement('Placemark');
            $placeNode = $docNode->appendChild($node);

            // Creates an id attribute and assign it the value of id column.
            $placeNode->setAttribute('id', 'placemark' . $row['buildingID']);

              // Create name, and description elements and assigns them the values of the name and address columns from the results.
              $nameNode = $dom->createElement('name',htmlentities($row['name']));
              $placeNode->appendChild($nameNode);
              $styleUrl = $dom->createElement('styleUrl', $row['styleID']);
              $placeNode->appendChild($styleUrl);

              // Creates a Polygon element.
              $polygonNode = $dom->createElement('Polygon');
              $placeNode->appendChild($polygonNode);

              //Add extrude information
              $restExtrude = $dom->createElement('extrude', '1');
              $polygonNode->appendChild($restExtrude);

              //Add altitude information
              $restAltitude = $dom->createElement('altitudeMode', 'relativeToGround');
              $polygonNode->appendChild($restAltitude);

              //Add outerBoundaryIsNode
              $outerBoundaryIsNode = $dom->createElement('outerBoundaryIs');
              $polygonNode->appendChild($outerBoundaryIsNode);

              //Add LinearRing Node
              $LinearRingNode = $dom->createElement('LinearRing');
              $outerBoundaryIsNode->appendChild($LinearRingNode);

              //Adding information into linear ring node
              $tessellate = $dom->createElement('tessellate', '1');
              $LinearRingNode->appendChild($tessellate);

              // Creates a coordinates element and gives it the value of the lng and lat columns from the results.
              $coorStr = $row['longitude1'] . ','  . $row['latitude1'] . ' ' . $row['longitude2'] . ',' . $row['latitude2'] . ' ' . $row['longitude3'] . ',' . $row['latitude3'] . ' ' . $row['longitude4'] . ',' . $row['latitude4'] . ' ' . $row['longitude5'] . ',' . $row['latitude5'];
              $coorNode = $dom->createElement('coordinates', $coorStr);
              $LinearRingNode->appendChild($coorNode);
        }

        $kmlOutput = $dom->saveXML();
        header('Content-type: application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml');
        echo $kmlOutput;
```

I have checked the kml file generated by loading it into maps and I am happy with the result, however I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get my website to display whatever kml file my php file is generating. I just can't think how to do it. I have tried following what the tutorial suggests however I don't really understand what it's doing and I can't get it to work. Having developed php code to dynamically generated the kml file I assumed I have done the hard part, I feel I have have been wrong. Any advice would be much appreciated as it's quite important!

At the moment I'm using the following code:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=key
```

"
            type="text/javascript">

```
            var map;
            var geoXml; 
            var toggleState = 1;

    function initialize() 
    {
        if (GBrowserIsCompatible())
            {
                geoXml = new GGeoXml("Locationoffile.part");
                map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas")); 
                map.setCenter(new GLatLng(50.xxxxx,-1.xxxxxxx), 16); 
                map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
                 map.addOverlay(geoXml);
            }
    } 


function toggleMyKml() 
    {
    if (toggleState == 1) 
        {
        map.removeOverlay(geoXml);
        toggleState = 0;
        } 
    else 
        {
        map.addOverlay(geoXml);
        toggleState = 1;
        }
    }
```

To generate a map done by copying the output out of the php generated kml file into a static location. This works. How much will I need to edit this to get it to load my php file instead? I'm still a bit confused despite your help.

Comment: Besides the PHP tutorial, have you tried following this example for KmlLayer? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers

Comment: No but i'll have a read thanks

Comment: Oh man, you're writing Version 2 map code! The example I gave you is for maps V3. There is a GeoXML for V3 also but I found it to be useful only when you want to manipulate the KML data. I believe KmlLayer will be enough to display your data.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have done the hard part. To display a kml file on a Google Map, you can use a `KmlLayer`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayer). Keep in mind that the URL you provide to the `KmlLayer` constructor must be a publicly available URL, so you have to make sure that you are able to pass a URL that may be reached from the web. It is fine that the KML is generated dynamically, you just have to make it available for Google to retrieve. Google will then process the kml and generate a tile overlay. That is what will be returned from your call to: `new google.maps.KmlLayer`.

If you would like to test that your URL is producing valid kml, check out the [Galdos KML Validator](http://www.kmlvalidator.com/home.htm); you supply it with a URL and it will retrieve and attempt to parse your KML. It's a nice kml smoke test utility.

Comment: Thanks A lot!. So in using this method will the URL I specify to to the php file that generates the kml file?

Comment: Yes, it has to be whatever URL may be used to retrieve the kml file; the fact that it is generated on-the-fly won't matter, as long as Google can go to the URL you supply and retrieve the kml.

Comment: Thanks. I editted my OP with a further question. Any further assistance would be brilliant as it sounds like you really know what you're talking about. The webpage which calls the php file is available online, however the backend database is not. Will this prove problematic?

Comment: Nope, this is common. You will supply the URL to Google and they will come to that URL to retrieve the file. All Google knows is that they can visit that URL to get the file. As long as that is true, it doesn't matter that there is a component that hits a database and then dynamically creates the file. Google will never know the difference, as long as Google can hit that URL and get the kml back, all will flow from there. We do this for our map for multiple KML files.

Comment: I've just added some additional info about a free online KML Validator utility. It will help you to verify that your component is producing valid KML.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem. Google caches the kml files. You'd need to change the saved kml file name every time you made a new version. Without this, you'd keep getting old cached versions instead of the most recent.